# Extremely slow internet connection

Tags: networking, internet

So, I picked up a extremely powerful computer with Windows, but installed Ubuntu on him (the computer not has Windows anymore). After a lot of time trying to fix internet connection (when I installed Ubuntu, the computer connect to internet, but cannot access it, and also today ethernet *not* work, so I think it's not a option), I can get super-fast incredible internet connection speed of 1.5 Kb/s. I really need to download files with like 10GB, so this is not acceptable, also considering the fact that all the time the "Unsuccessful" text appears at Firefox, Chromium and using `wget` (with `wget` the text is a little different, but only for illustration).

I really need to fix this problem as fast as I can, and I think that the problem is with the network card (since in the two networks I work all time, other computers can access with gracefully 1 Gb/s of internet, and me with destroying 1.5 Kb/s), but I need suggestions of what to do.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The output of `sudo lshw -C network` is (sorry for the text in portuguese):

```
  *-network               
       descrição: Interface sem fio
       produto: RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       fabricante: Ralink corp.
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       nome lógico: wlo1
       versão: 00
       serial: 9c:2a:70:0b:55:c4
       largura: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuração: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.10.0-42-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.15.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:19 memória:d4500000-d450ffff
  *-network
       descrição: Ethernet interface
       produto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       nome lógico: eno1
       versão: 07
       serial: a0:b3:cc:4d:33:4b
       tamanho: 10Mbit/s
       capacidade: 1Gbit/s
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuração: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:27 porta de E/S:2000(tamanho=256) memória:d4404000-d4404fff memória:d4400000-d4403fff
```

And also, I forget to mention a very strange behavior: as more as I use internet, the connection speed gets better. For example, I am downloading a 600MB file on Firefox, with terrible 800 bytes per second. But, if I start downloading the same file with `wget` on a terminal simultaneously, I can get even 790Kb/s on both downloads at the same time (but Firefox generally is slower than that).

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo lshw -C network` and add the output to your question